# Custom instagram oauth login php/ios

Tags: php, ios, oauth, instagram

Cant figure out how to create a custom login screen and then authenticating the user to instagram. I have used different instagram php classes which of course will send you to the instagram website for the login interface and then call back to the callback url.

I have seen this type of custom login within the app "famousgram" for ios. They have a custom login screen, you fill your instagram details and login. you never get the instagram login screen.

For iOS i have used the oauth2swift lib. and of course either you get the webview to instagram login, or use safari and then call to the appcomname// back.

The way i would like to do this is just: make a simple login screen in my ios. then call a function to request my php http://hello.com/instagram_login.php web service. the webservice will log in to instagram and return the auth code, and profile info back to the app.

Comment: Asking a user for their login details on a custom login view defeats the point of oAuth and looks shady at best. How do I know you're not intercepting my information? You should stick to showing the normal Instagram interface.

Comment: @bgilham can you please check the Famousgram app ? i don't know how they do it..

Comment: by the way..have you used the  https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift  lib ? when implementing with instagram i can get the credential.oauth_token , but theres no crendential.profile, credential.userid ,etc? in instagram theres  no end point like /me/ or /users/me . i can't seem to find a way to get the user details such as pic,userid,name,etc..

Comment: That's not oAuth. That's straight up using people's login and pass. Like I said, shady.

Comment: Famousgram is not a good example of how you should be doing this.